# Very easy game builders?

Tags: tools, game-maker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good game development programs for kids?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9460/what-are-some-good-game-development-programs-for-kids)

I want very easy game builder for a kid - somebody who knows nothing about programming games (how they work inside) and just wants to build some (I could teach him but I am not available all the time). She tried Adventure Maker and got confused. It has to be something very straightforward. Do You know about any? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Alice](http://www.alice.org/) by Carnegie Mellon University, was built explicitly for teaching those with no knowledge of programming, how to construct apps, by visually building interactive environments and simple games. It's well-geared for kids from what I've seen. The interface is good and allows you to build simple 3D games with basic parameters, teaching you Java as you go -- but it leads one very gently into the coding aspect.

Answer (score 3):

[Kodu](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/kodu/), a visual game-making framework by Microsoft Research, was designed with kids in mind. It runs on an XBox 360 and uses a controller for input.